# Newbie trying to understand emacs filing system

Tags: init-file, files

This is my first time here. I asked my question over at /r/emacs on reddit, however so far I am left with some unanswered questions. I'll copy paste my question along with the link to my post which has more information.

[Original Post](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2ve9j6/newbie_trying_to_understand_emacs_filing_system/)

---

Hi,

Before emacs I thought I knew my computer, now after learning, or trying to learn emacs I am not so sure and feel like an 80 year old with dementia. Anyways, I am not sure if this happens to everyone or I am just not doing it right.

Back to my question. I am learning emacs to write screenplays and notes and also use it as a planner/organizer/manager. I plan to make it my one stop from writing to having my film list to small notes and books and what have you. I am mighty impressed with all the packages available which will make writing much fun.

While previously I worked with Files and Folders and it got a bit too messy. I understand there is an extension called helm which makes file management a breeze. I've been playing with packages and Dired. I understand how emacs works and how it goes about doing its business. I think about files and folders and emacs talks about directory and sub-directory (sub-folders).

Let me run you through what I did and how I messed up or I think I messed up, again :

I unzipped emacs to > C:\Users\MyName\OneDrive\emacs

My .emacs folder lands up in C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming.emacs.d

Along with 3 emacs files / #.emacs# / .emacs and .emacs~ in 
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming

When I type C-x C-f it takes me to C:\Users\MyName\OneDrive\emacs\bin/

When I look up other tutorials I notice that their emacs files are in their home directory and not else where. Also when I customize it does make changes to one of the files in C:\Users\My\AppData\Roaming however the package gets installed in C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming.emacs.d\elpa

and then the customization never shows up even after package-initialize and package-require. So I am guessing my Emacs isn't picking up on the right file or I messed up.
Can I not have .emacs.d and those 3 files in my home directory 
C:\Users\MyName\OneDrive\emacs\bin/

How have you set up your emacs?

What is the best way to go about file management and not have things cluttered and mixed up.

Is there some sort of an optimal setup?

Thanks for your help.

---

This [thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2ve9j6/newbie_trying_to_understand_emacs_filing_system/coh0tbc) is the solution I am trying to implement.

Comment: Where did you download your Emacs version, and what version of Windows are you using, and what version of Emacs are you using -- type `M-x emacs-version RET`?  For example, did you download `emacs-24.4-bin-i686-pc-mingw32.zip` from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/ ?  Do you know what your home directory is?

Comment: I also found this very confusing at first. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189490/where-can-i-find-my-emacs-file-for-emacs-running-on-windows

Comment: @lawlist : This version - GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2014-10-24 on LEG570. And I am on Windows 7. I don't know what my home directory is. I guess it's C/Users/MyName/AppData/Roaming.

Comment: I prefer to leave my home directory variables untouched, and instead I merely adjust the `user-emacs-directory` as *zck* has suggested below.  I also keep the `.emacs` file in the home directory with just one line that looks like this -- `(load-file "y:/.0.emacs/.0.lisp/init.el")` -- that one-liner loads my entire library of user customizations.  My `user-emacs-directory` is set to `"y:/.0.emacs/"`, so the creation of just about everything occurs naturally in that directory -- e.g., when adding packages using `M-x list-packages`.  You can even change that location with the `package-user-dir`.

Comment: If you want to suppress the loading message caused by `load-file` (which message appears in the `*Messages*` buffer), you can use the following one-liner in its place:  `(load "y:/.0.emacs/.0.lisp/init.el" nil t t nil)`

Comment: This question is far too broad for Stack Exchange, and should be closed. Split it into multiple questions, please. And please do not include questions that are primarily opinion-based. See the S.E. help for [how to ask a good question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @drew hey, sorry, I am new here and quite don't know how this place works. I'll read the guidelines and post a new question.

Comment: No problem - it's good to read the guidelines; thx. But anyway, mine is just one opinion. ;-)

Comment: @lawlist I guess this has overloaded my system. Is this somewhat complicated or am I doing something wrong. I think I am missing something here. Why is this so difficult to get a grip of. Do you think I should not make the changes and instead do what you suggest.

Comment: @curious-scribbler -- I don't want to discourage you, but it's possible to spend a zillion hours customizing Emacs to do exactly what you want -- some customizations will take a few minutes and others will take an *enormous* amount of time that requires posting questions and reading all kinds of Google search results.  If you really want to move your home directory and that will make you happy, then by all means go ahead and do so.  I am obsessive compulsive, and need things a certain way -- so I would completely understand if having your home directory somewhere else will make you happy.  :)

Comment: @lawlist this whole thing started because I wanted things to be in a particular way that is to set up init.el. I think I will drop changing HOME because it appears to be a bit confusing for me now. And I reading [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsDotD) only pushes me further into confusion.

Comment: @lawlist particularly this last paragraph "The user directory itself is not part of load-path, and since it contains other things than libraries, you should leave it at that. Instead, you should install packages in a dedicated sub-directory (e.g., ~/.emacs.d/elisp) and add that to the load-path instead."

Comment: @curious-scribbler -- I would suggest starting off very slowly using primarily the default settings and make very minor customizations -- e.g., colors, default fonts, keywords for highlighting.  It's been 1.5 years since I started using Emacs and I'm still customizing it a little bit more each day; and, I still have a list of bug-fixes and/or customizations to make whenever I have free time.  Now that I think back in time, I probably tried using Emacs on a few different occasions until I finally took the plunge.  I still modify my Emacs configurations using a different editor -- SublimeText2.

Comment: @curious-scribbler -- Here is an example of a load-path configuration -- I can't put it in highlight in these comments because of one special symbol -- i.e., the backtick -- it requires the manual creation of three directories -- creating `lisp`, `themes` and `miscellaneous`.  In the example in the comments above, I use hidden directories with a dot that precedes the directory name -- that is just my personal preference for alphabetizing:  (defvar root.d "y:/emacs/") (setq load-path (append `( ,(concat root.d "lisp") ,(concat root.d "themes") ,(concat root.d "miscellaneous") ) load-path))

Comment: @lawlist I am going to save this and come back to it when I have gathered some more knowledge of how to go about making the changes that you suggest. The problem is that I still don['t really understand how and why things are the way they are. As you said, somethings require more work. I have to first understand why things are the way they are when it's initially set up and how my customization is going to change things. I am jumping over a few valleys here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a few things to solve:

1. How do you set up an emacs config file?
2. Where do you store files?
3. How do you access files? Is Helm helpful?

Let's deal with those separately.

### How do you set up an emacs config file?

As mentioned elsewhere, Emacs looks in the directory indicated by the [HOME](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init) environment variable. You should make sure this is set. What should you set it to? That's up to you, but probably something like `C:\Users\MyName\`.

You can also find where Emacs is currently looking by inspecting the variable `user-emacs-directory`. To do this, press `C-h v`, then type `user-emacs-directory` and press Enter. A buffer will open telling you, among other things, what Emacs currently thinks is the user directory.

### Where do you store files?

Emacs can access files stored anywhere on your machine; it doesn't matter where they are. That is to say, you can access files in `C:\Users\MyName\OneDrive\emacs\bin/`, but also, for example, files in `C:\Users\MyName\Documents` or `C:\Users\MyName\Pictures`. Or even just in `C:\otherFolder\`. You probably want to have some sort of organization scheme, but that doesn't really make a difference for Emacs accessing them.

### How do you access files? Is Helm helpful?

You can navigate to any directory by pressing `C-x C-f`, then typing the path to the file. Helm is useful for finding files; you may want to [check it out](http://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/).

If you have follow-up questions, you should post a separate question for each one. Stack Overflow works best when each question is narrow in scope.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will be going through helm for sure, however before that I am stuck with setting up my .emacs.d folder to a new place. 

I was suggested on reddit, (the thread is linked in my post above) that I should create a new .emacs.d folder and instead of .emacs file, I should create a init.el and change my home variable to point to the new location where I have created the .emacs.d. Have you read that thread?

Comment: Can you post a new question that's only about getting your .emacs.d folder set up? It's hard to help out in the comments here.

Comment: Sure, I'll post a separate question for each issue. Thanks for your help.